# How to disable related_products woocomerce only in mobile view

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

For fast loading in mobile view i want to remove woocommerce related products, what is the code to be added in function.php?
and I do not want to use CSS, thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `woocommerce_output_related_products` is pluggable.  So you can just re-write it.

See: [WooCommerce Code Reference](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-template-functions.html#source-view.1923)

Include this in your functions.php

```php
function woocommerce_output_related_products() {
    // Check if mobile and bail if so.
    if (wp_is_mobile()) return;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'columns'        => 4,
        'orderby'        => 'rand', // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine.
    );

    woocommerce_related_products( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', $args ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress inbuilt function - `wp_is_mobile()`
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/

your complete code will be-

```
if (wp_is_mobile()) {
     remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
}
```

Comment: thank you i had similar codes , also i tested your code but it did not work unfortunately

Comment: thanks you for letting me know. I will also check at my end.